# How to fix unwanted exceptions from JSON.parse() commands

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js

Authenticate is okay when the user info is correct but upon entering wrong details the server crashes

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'password',
  passportField: 'username'
},
        function(username, password, done) {
          con.query("SELECT * FROM uids WHERE list =" +"'" + username + "'", function (err, result) {
            if (err) done(err);
            var clean =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))[0].list //Expected Result :  test2
                      //from [ RowDataPacket { list: 'test2' } ]

              //no user was found

          if(username === clean) {
              //Success
              return done(null, true);
          } else {
              //Wrong password
              return done(null, false);
          }
            });
        }
    ));
```

Error From server:

```
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
```

I understand what is wrong but i dont know if there is a function to check if the list even exists

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "dawg111",
  password: "poopingboy111",
   database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connection to Database is ok!");
});

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username',
  passportField: 'password'
},
        function(username, password, done) {
          con.query('SELECT * FROM uids WHERE list = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
          });
        }
    ));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188028/discussion-on-question-by-jacktheninja-how-to-fix-unwanted-exceptions-from-json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no need for either `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse` here. You don't have any JSON. `results` should already be an array, so you can work with it directly without having to convert it to or from JSON.

If you want to check that there's definitely a result then `if (results)` will ensure the results variable is defined (although I suspect it always will be, but sometimes might have no entries within it).

So therefore if `results` is defined, and you want to check the number of rows then `if (results.length > 0)` will do the job - this is how you check the length of any JavaScript array.

So overall you can do something like this:

```
      con.query('SELECT * FROM uids WHERE list = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;// ok
        console.log(results); // [ RowDataPacket { list: 'test2' } ]

        if (results.length > 0){
          var clean = results[0].list //Expected Result :  test2

          if(username === clean) {
            //Success
            return done(null, true);
//...etc
```